# get token from OAuth request client

Tags: go, oauth, oauth-2.0, cloud-foundry

I’ve the following code which I want to get the token from the request , I pass the **API/ClientSecret/ClientID**

```
r := fmt.Sprintf("https://tenenat.host.com/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&response_type=token&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s", CI, CS)
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, r, nil)
req.Header.Set("accept", "application/json")
res, err := httpClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(os.Stdout)
    var t OAuthAccessResponse
    if err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&t); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(os.Stdout, "could not parse JSON response: %v", err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
}
```

When running it I got error :

http 400 bad request .

Any idea if I miss something in the request ?

Im not able to format the code right :)

Comment: From review: I'm not very knowledgeable on this topic, but I guess the " " everywhere in your code (do they display for you?) might have to do with it. For me it appears as a block-type character containing (L SEP). Looks like this is unicode `U+2028` or HTML entity code `&#8232;`.

Comment: Can you post a link to the oauth API of the host? I've already sent an edit request, once approved, your formatting will be right.

Answer (score 0):

If avoidable, you should not be placing sensitive data, such as client secret, in the URL string.  It is less secure than using the message body: for example it may be captured in logs and site traffic analytics that end up being shared with third parties.

Instead, do a POST with a JSON body:

```
type TokenRequest struct {
    GrantType    string `json:"grant_type"`
    ResponseType string `json:"response_type"`
    ClientID     string `json:"client_id"`
    ClientSecret string `json:"client_secret"`
}
tokenReq := &TokenRequest{
    GrantType:    grantType,
    ResponseType: responseType,
    ClientID:     clientID,
    ClientSecret: clientSecret,
}
body, err := json.Marshal(tokenReq)
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("Failed to marshal request body: %s", err)
}
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(body))
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("Failed to create request: %s", err)
}
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
res, err := httpClient.Do(req)
```

### Update

OP is now getting a statuscode 401 response.  401 is unauthorized.  You probably need to authenticate to the API.  For example, if you have a bearer token, add a header for it prior to making your request:

```
req.Header.Set("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", bearer))
```

Comment: Thanks, does it mandatory to provide the `grant type` and `response type` , I currently only have the `url` `client_id` `secret`

Comment: in addition im getting now response 401 , any idea what it could be? is guess this is improvement, isnt it?

Comment: also in the `url` I should put only `https://tenenat.host.com/oauth/token` this ?

Comment: for `grantType` Type I didnt provide anything, does it related to the `401` ? and `repsonseType="token"`

Comment: I've put    `GrantType:    "client_credentials",`
  `ResponseType: "token",` and still having `401` what it could be? maybe the url format ? im using `https://tenenat.host.com/oauth/token`

Comment: Thanks, from where sholud i take the bearer value ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the url that you are using, but in my case it is an AWS Cognito one, and I could not get a bearer token if the request was json formatted -- it had to be "url encoded".  It may be that your endpoint should be treated the same way?

Anyhow here is the code that worked for me getting the **client_credentials** bearer token from AWS Cognito.

```
// "url encode" the request data
bodyData := url.Values{}
bodyData.Set("client_id", clientID)
bodyData.Set("grant_type", "client_credentials")
bodyData.Set("scope", clientScope)
body := bodyData.Encode()
bodyBuffer := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(body))

// create the post request
httpRequest, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", tokenEndpointURL, bodyBuffer)
httpRequest.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
httpRequest.SetBasicAuth(url.QueryEscape(clientID), url.QueryEscape(clientSecret))

// post the request
httpClient := &http.Client{}
httpResponse, err := httpClient.Do(httpRequest)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error with http client do: %v", err)
    return "", err
}
defer httpResponse.Body.Close()

// read the response
responseBuffer, err := ioutil.ReadAll(httpResponse.Body)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error reading http response body: %v", err)
    return "", err
}
responseJSON := string(responseBuffer)
fmt.Printf("responseJSON: %v", responseJSON)

// unmarshal the response
type ClientCredentialsTokenResponseStruct struct {
    AccessToken string `json:"access_token"`
    TokenType   string `json:"token_type"`
    ExpiresIn   int    `json:"expires_in"`
}

var tokenResponse ClientCredentialsTokenResponseStruct
_ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(responseJSON), &tokenResponse)
```

The bearer token is in `tokenResponse.AccessToken`.

Good luck!